# Canvas drawImage with large images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I am trying to make is some kind of scrollable viewport in which a really large image is loaded (as in 10.000 x 10.000 pixels or more) and I should be able to draw some lines / shapes on this image.

There are two methods I can think of to draw the image / allowing the shapes to be drawn:

- Using an  tag to draw the image and draw a canvas the size of the image above it.
- Using the drawImage() method to draw the image and just use a canvas.

I have tried both cases but when I load an image (in the img tag or using the javascript Image() object) it consumes about 500MB of memory.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: What about breaking the image into tiles and only loading the tiles as you scroll near them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never *ever* make a user download an image that size unless you absolutely have to.

Make 100 smaller tiles (or thereabouts) of the image and draw the tiles to the Canvas, only drawing the tiles that can be seen at the current time (like google maps, etc do).

Comment: Thanks! I've made a small test project and tiling is the way to go.